# How to make a always unchecked checkbox without using disabled in vue.js?

Tags: forms, vue.js, checkbox

I need the checkbox to be always unchecked.
I tried by binding the checked attribute to a false property from data and set @input/change listener to do nothing and using v-model but none of them does work as expected.

[Code here](https://jsfiddle.net/gkaeryu0/)

Comment: You could also add `:disabled` stopping users from clicking on it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/uv2hntba/

handle the click event (e) and call e.preventDefault()

or use the @click.prevent shortcut

js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
    preventThisClickEvent(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
})
```

html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" :checked="checked" @click="preventThisClickEvent" /> prevent by method
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" :checked="checked" @click.prevent="doNothing" /> prevent by shortcut
</div>
```